# TypeScript throws error when trying to index an object that I have casted to DefaultValues<T> in React-Hook-Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I've created a custom hook that allows you to define a configuration object for forms using React Hook Form. Now, I'm attempting to include default values from the configuration object into the **`useForm`** configuration. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to access properties of the **`defaultValues`** object, which I have type-casted to **`DefaultValues<T>`** from React-Hook-Form.

```
  const defaultValues = {} as DefaultValues<FormFieldIds>;

  const entries = Object.entries(config) as Array<
    [FieldPath<FormFieldIds>, FormFieldConfig<FormFieldIds>]
  >;

  entries.forEach(([id, formFieldConfig]) => {
    if (formFieldConfig.defaultValue) {
      defaultValues[id] = formFieldConfig.defaultValue;
    }
  });
```

[See codesandbox with the hook and error message here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-morning-9ccpg4?file=/src/hooks/formHook.tsx)`

How can I tell TypeScript that the id is the right type?

**Solution**

Comment from Golamrabbi Azad:

```
const defaultValues = {} as DefaultValues<FormFieldIds>[FieldPath<FormFieldIds>]
```

Comment: Assert the defaultValue type `as DefaultValues<FormFieldIds>[FieldPath<FormFieldIds>]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Cool, mark it as the answer. It'll help to understand if anyone comes to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we are telling the TypeScript compiler to treat the empty object to the specific type I give you.

```
const defaultValues = {} as DefaultValues<FormFieldIds>[FieldPath<FormFieldIds>]
```